# Deploy 1:1 Teams bot to all users at once

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I would like to deploy my 1:1 Teams bot to all users in an O365 tenant as a company admin. How do I do that? I know how to get a Manifest in the Org's app store but it seems I can only deploy it for myself. For obvious reasons I can't expect my 2.000+ users to do that.

I know there is a previous question about this ([Microsoft Teams: How to provide a 1:1 chat bot globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46905097/microsoft-teams-how-to-provide-a-11-chat-bot-globally)) but it seems outdated and I don't see a real solution here

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/publishing/apps-publish

Comment: Aware of that document. Unless I misinterpret, this does not explain how to deploy a Teams 1:1 bot to all O365 users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a fairly simple way to do it assuming some programming, of course.

Use the MSFT Graph API to add the contact to the user's contact List, then it'll show on the 1:1 chat tab.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-contacts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs

Since it is a *user's contact* it also allows to set a picture and a custom name.

EDIT:

I then realised this would not list in the 1:1 chat tab because it wouldn't appear there until there is an interaction. Also not sure how the contact should be populated...

My suggestion would that from the bot itself you sent a welcome message to every user, this will make sure that everyone has in in 1:1.

Comment: To be able to send a message to everybody proactively I am gonna need an AD sync up front probably?

Comment: Too bad the first suggestion seems not an option ( ? ) This would solve my other name + icon issue....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55992247/is-it-possible-to-load-another-bot-with-different-branding-to-a-teams-app/56010085?noredirect=1#comment98694201_56010085

Comment: Yes, you would need to sync the AD and get all the contact you wish to send the messsage to. Also there is an issue that new users won't receive that message.... maybe every month scan for new users... ?

Comment: Using Proactive messages can definitively solve this: [Proactive Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)
If this helped you consider marking it as the correct answer :D

Comment: Regarding AD sync, you'll be fine use Graph API: List Users and users delta (for new users)

Comment: I would like to re-open this discussion.. Finding the bot through some proactive message (if possible at all to open a message to a user we found through an AD sync) will result in a bot at "chat" but not an installed bot through the (local company) store. If this bot is not installed "Task Modules" is impossible.. This is one of the most important features in my bot.. 

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to deploy your bot only to your company not globally. ? if that is the case, once you have your bot ready with manifest.json file. Then you have to follow the

> Publish apps to the Microsoft Teams Tenant Apps Catalog

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/tenant-apps-catalog-teams

Alternatively this is a bit of cheeky way.

Assuming if all your 2000+ users in one Company Teams / Channel. As an Admin you can install your bot in to that channel. Then every one can access the bot using @ mentions of your Bot.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes company not globally.. 
I really want it in the 1:1 chat section.. but.. to everybody.. This documentation explains how to make a bot available but my users would still all have to add it from this org's app store..

Comment: Did you check the "Use the Office 365 admin portal to manage the Tenant Apps Catalog" which has mentioned clearly about 'dedicated to your company's apps'

Comment: Yes I checked it and turned on.. but nothing.. check this out
Teams bot deployed as admin - http://prntscr.com/npaq8f
App enabled - http://prntscr.com/npb9pt
Other user doesn't see this bot - http://prntscr.com/npba0e

The example doesnt represent a real customer - it's a demo